# Preparing Deployment - failed

Tags: publishing, deployer

Items are failing at "Preparing Deployment" phase, when logs are checked on Deployer, I could see below:

> 2017-07-10 11:40:53,576 WARN  DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployer
>   Prepare Phase failure message: Unable to rename package to
>   D:\InetPub\Staging\Incoming\Zip\tcm_0-817263-66560.Content.zip for
>   transaction: tcm:0-817263-66560 2017-07-10 11:40:53,592 ERROR
>   DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployer Prepare
>   Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-817263-66560 2017-07-10
>   11:40:53,592 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for
>   transaction: tcm:0-817263-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to rename package to
>   D:\InetPub\Staging\Incoming\Zip\tcm_0-817263-66560.Content.zip    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.UnzipWorker.doWork(UnzipWorker.java:95)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreparePhase.execute(PreparePhase.java:45)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>   2017-07-10 11:40:53,592 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start
>   processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-817263-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployer Prepare
>   Phase failed.  Unable to rename package to
>   D:\InetPub\Staging\Incoming\Zip\tcm_0-817263-66560.Content.zip    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>   Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to rename
>   package to
>   D:\InetPub\Staging\Incoming\Zip\tcm_0-817263-66560.Content.zip    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.UnzipWorker.doWork(UnzipWorker.java:95)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreparePhase.execute(PreparePhase.java:45)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  ... 9 common frames omitted 2017-07-10
>   11:40:53,592 WARN  DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployer Prepare
>   Phase failure message: null for transaction: tcm:0-817263-66560
>   2017-07-10 11:40:53,592 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt
>   in Phase: Deployer Prepare Phase failed for transaction:
>   tcm:0-817263-66560 2017-07-10 11:40:53,592 ERROR
>   DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for transaction:
>   tcm:0-817263-66560 java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException:
>   null  at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.tridion.util.FileUtils.getExclusiveFileLock(FileUtils.java:703)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.marshalToFile(JAXBUtil.java:126)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.distribution.deployer.DeployerTransaction.update(DeployerTransaction.java:200)
>   ~[cd_model.jar:na]    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]
>     at
>   com.tridion.distribution.TransactionItem.complete(TransactionItem.java:139)
>   ~[cd_model.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.UnzipWorker.doWork(UnzipWorker.java:107)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreparePhase.execute(PreparePhase.java:45)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>   2017-07-10 11:40:53,592 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start
>   processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-817263-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Phase: Deployer Prepare
>   Phase failed.  null   at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:209)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:100)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:64)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:82)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>   Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException: null   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.tridion.util.FileUtils.getExclusiveFileLock(FileUtils.java:703)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.marshalToFile(JAXBUtil.java:126)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.distribution.deployer.DeployerTransaction.update(DeployerTransaction.java:200)
>   ~[cd_model.jar:na]    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]
>     at
>   com.tridion.distribution.TransactionItem.complete(TransactionItem.java:139)
>   ~[cd_model.jar:na]    at
>   com.tridion.deployer.workers.UnzipWorker.doWork(UnzipWorker.java:107)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreparePhase.execute(PreparePhase.java:45)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:198)
>   [cd_deployer.jar:na]  ... 9 common frames omitted 2017-07-10
>   11:40:59,613 ERROR QueueLocationHandler - Unable to unmarshall the
>   deployer transaction for the given transaction: tcm:0-817292-66560
>   javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: null   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:213)
>   ~[jaxb-impl.jar:2.1.12]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
>   ~[jaxb-impl.jar:2.1.12]   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.unmarshalFromFile(JAXBUtil.java:156)
>   ~[cd_core.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionStateManager.loadTransaction(TransactionStateManager.java:62)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionStateManager.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionStateManager.java:43)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:74)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:180)
>   ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.7.0_121]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_121]
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   because another process has locked a portion of the file  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_121]  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.7.0_121]   at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
>   ~[jaxb-impl.jar:2.1.12]   ... 15 common frames omitted

Any clues?

Comment: check your deployer's config where its receiving package, make sure there is no in-progress item in publishing queue, then clean the folder completely.

Comment: @RajKumar, any idea why this could have occurred?

Comment: just go to D:\InetPub\Staging\Incoming\ and clean the folder,  let me know if works or not. i am not sure but could be name clash/ disk space.

Comment: Or anti-virus. Looks like another process is locking that file. Could also be another deployer process using the same file location

Comment: @NunoLinhares, we have 2 deployers active and staging, but both use different file locations. Not sure about anti-virus issue

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear on the actual failure:

> Unable to rename package to D:\InetPub\Staging\Incoming\Zip\tcm_0-817263-66560.Content.zip

So it appears something is locking that file, which could be anything, to figure out what, you can best use the Windows Process Explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

There are a few things you should check for;

- Does the identity under which the Deployer processes are running have enough rights to create, update and delete files?
- Are the file locations for queue and incoming folder separate in the Deployer configuration?
- Are no multiple Deployer processes configured for the same locations?
- Could there be Anti Virus software locking the incoming or temp files?

Comment: Thanks Bart. This issue is happening, whenever there is a large publishing done and is happening with only few items and that too intermittently. 

And we did not see any Zip files getting locked. Also today (around 4k publishings, together for active and staging) we saw following errors in logs: 
2017-07-14 11:21:37,816 ERROR UnzipWorker - Unable to clean unzip location.
java.io.IOException: D:\Inetpub\Staging\incoming\Zip\tcm_0-830058-66560.Content is not a folder!  

Not able to get the root cause.